# Setting up different environment variables for local development vs expo go vs prod for react native

Tags: react-native

can someone suggest best practices on environment variable setup for react native apps ? Specifically on local machine I would like to connect to my locally hosted database instance, then when testing on expo on friends devices I would like to provide a different database url and eventually when building for app store I would like provide production database instance url. I have read about react-native-dotenv package however I am not clear how I ask expo to use a different config when starting the app locally vs expo vs prod environment ?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/,